# How can an isolating tape be used as a connection to the human body?

Tags: connector, isolation

I'm making this project: [Drawdio](http://makezine.com/projects/drawdio-musical-pencil/)
There are 2 connections with the human body: one via the graphite and the other with a grip made of isolating tape. I don't see how this work. This tape isolates the electric wire that is running around the pencil, so how can this serve as a connection? Or do you make a capacitor = electrical wire/isolating tape/human body that can conduct electricity?

Answer (score 1):

The wire wrapped around the pencil is bare - it makes contact with the user's hand.  The tape around the bottom of the pencil is just used to keep the wire in place.  If you wrap the tape all the way up the pencil, insulating the wire (or don't strip the insulation off the wire) the thing probably won't work.

Comment: So it isn't so imported if this is isolated or not if it is just to keep the wire in place?

Comment: As I read the instructions, the wire must be bare, and contact the user's hand.  The tape just keeps the wire in place - it is not there to provide insulation.